# Does exist operator | Vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm doing an exercise that I have to find the erros of VHDL code, I won't paste the code straight here, because it's a print.

At a moment, there is this part of code:

with E select
   S <= "001" when "110"|"100"|"000",

if this operator "|" exists, I can notice the difference between | and "or".

But does it exists?

Comment: I haven't seen it that operator yet. Most probably, as you said, it should be "or"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exists.  It's not an operator, it's a delimiter. (IEEE Std 1076-1993, 13.2 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters).

From your question it would appear you're finding it hard to find support in the LRM.  There are various places BNF is normative in the text of the standard outside of the Appendix containing the syntax summary.

From IEEE Std 1076-1993:

> 8.8 Case statement
>
> ....

```
case_statement_alternative ::=  
    when choices =>
         sequence_of_statements
```

> ....
>
> The simple expression and discrete ranges given as choices in a case statement
>   must be locally static. A choice defined by a discrete range stands for all 
>   values in the corresponding range. The choice others is only allowed for the 
>   last alternative and as its only choice; it stands for all values(possibly 
>       none) not given in the choices of previous alternatives. An element simple 
>       name (see 7.3.2 ) is not allowed as a choice of a case statement alternative.
>
> 7.3.2 Aggregates
>   ...

```
 choices ::=  choice { | choice }

 choice ::=
       simple_expression
     | discrete_range
     | element_simple_name
     | others
```

The delimiter vertical bar ('|') is used to separate choices.  A choice in a case statement alternative can't be an element simple name.  Your example shows choices that are simple expressions.