# Writing this selected signal assignment in a more compact way

Tags: vhdl

I have an 8-bit signal `all_inputs` that I am feeding into a selected signal assignment on a signal W1, as shown below:

```
with all_inputs select W1 <=
    '1' when "010001",
    '1' when "100100",
    '1' when "001100",
    '0' when others;
```

I want to know if there is a way to combine the string literals into one line to write it more compactly. If I had more signal values to add, it would get tedious quickly.
I've tried:

```
with all_inputs select W1 <=
    '1' when "010001" or "100100" or "001100",
    '0' when others;
```

Which does synthesize, but seems to treat the expression as a bitwise OR operation, where I want a logical treatment of these values. Surrounding the string literals with `()`s gives me a syntax error.

Any ideas on how I can make these assignments a little more compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21800622/13351293) answer has exactly what I was looking for - the `|` (pipe/vertical bar) operator:

> The delimiter vertical bar ('|') is used to separate choices.

So, changing this:

```
with all_inputs select W1 <=
    '1' when "010001" or "100100" or "001100",
    '0' when others;
```

to this:

```
with all_inputs select W1 <=
    '1' when "010001" | "100100" | "001100",
    '0' when others;
```

Now sets `W1` to 1 when `all_inputs` is any of the three provided string literals,

***rather than***

when `all_inputs` is the bitwise-OR of those signals.